# Swiftで、実装中に変数やメソッドの一覧を素早く確認したい

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, macos

Objective-Cでは、常にヘッダファイルを表示することで、クラスのインターフェースを確認しながら実装することができました。しかし、Swiftではヘッダファイルがなくなってしまい不自由に感じています。
Xcode のストラクチャパネルで一覧は見れるものの、ソートできないですし、パブリック/プライベート等のアクセス修飾子もわかりません。コードを折り畳むのも試しましたが、ダイナミックに値を返すタイプのプロパティは折りたためないようです。

そもそも、クラスのインターフェースを常に表示しておきたいという考え方は少数派なのでしょうか？
SwiftをはじめPHP等のヘッダファイルがない言語では、みなさんどのようにされているかご意見を伺えると幸いです。

Comment: 同じクラスのメンバを呼び出すコードを書くときに、そのクラスのメンバ一覧が見たい、ということでしょうか？あるいは別のクラスのヘッダが見たいのでしょうか？

Comment: @unarist コメントありがとうございます。そのクラス（編集中のクラス）のメンバ一覧を表示できればと思っています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCodeでは、`self.`とタイプすることで編集中のクラスのフィールドなどが出てくるのでそれを活用する手があります。

Javaもヘッダファイルのない言語ですが、EclipseなどのIDEの機能を活用することでメンバーリストを表示することができます。

と、ここまで書いてて気づいたのですが、継承があるのでクラスのインターフェースを「全部出す」のは難しいですよね。。。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

なるほど、コード補完の活用いいですね！`self._`でプロパティの一覧だけを表示などできたら便利そうです。（Swiftではそのような命名の慣習はないようですが。）

それから、Eclipseの画面（アウトラインペイン？）も見てみました。変数や引数の型やアクセス修飾子まで表示でき便利そうですね。

読んでいて思ったのですが、最近はIDEが便利になり、ヘッダファイルの必要性がうすくなってきたということがあるのかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 0):

外部フレームワークのクラスの場合、Jump to Definitionで定義に飛ぶことができるので、これをAssistant Editorに表示しておけば、インターフェースを把握するという意味では十分かと思います。（少なくとも、Objective-Cのヘッダファイルと情報量的には変わらないかと）

自作のクラスについては・・・　Xcodeのコード補間で把握できるように、わかりやすい構成を自分で工夫すればいいんじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。なるほど、確かに外部フレームワークなら実装が隠されていますものね。目からうろこでした。
自作クラスについては、仰るとおりですね。Swiftでは、プロパティやメソッド名にプリフィックスを付けたコードをあまり見かけないため悩ましいです。（好きに命名すれば良いと言われればそれまでなのですが・・・）